# Primefaces : how to create <p:menubar> dynamically in primefaces 4?

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, menubar

i'm migrating from primefaces 3.4 to primfaces 4.I had the menubar created dinamically in primefaces 3.4 with no probleme.
here is the bean:

```
public MenuBean() {
    MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
    Submenu submenu = new Submenu();


    submenu.setLabel("Nos Solutions");
    menuItem.setValue("Computers");
    menuItem.setUrl("#");
    submenu.getChildren().add(menuItem);

    menuItem = new MenuItem();
    menuItem.setValue("Clothes");
    menuItem.setUrl("#");
    submenu.getChildren().add(menuItem);

    simpleMenuModel.addSubmenu(submenu);

    submenu = new Submenu();
    submenu.setLabel("Nos Problemes");
    menuItem.setValue("Computers");
    menuItem.setUrl("#");
    submenu.getChildren().add(menuItem);

    menuItem = new MenuItem();
    menuItem.setValue("Clothes");
    menuItem.setUrl("#");
    submenu.getChildren().add(menuItem);

    simpleMenuModel.addSubmenu(submenu);

    submenu = new Submenu();
    submenu.setLabel("Nos Solutions");
    menuItem.setValue("Computers");
    menuItem.setUrl("#");
    submenu.getChildren().add(menuItem);

    menuItem = new MenuItem();
    menuItem.setValue("Clothes");
    menuItem.setUrl("#");
    submenu.getChildren().add(menuItem);

    simpleMenuModel.addSubmenu(submenu);

    submenu = new Submenu();
    submenu.setLabel("Nos Solutions");
    menuItem.setValue("Computers");
    menuItem.setUrl("#");
    submenu.getChildren().add(menuItem);

    Submenu submenu1 = new Submenu();
    submenu1.setLabel("Offres");
    menuItem = new MenuItem();
    menuItem.setValue("Stage Etudiants");
    menuItem.setUrl("#");
    submenu1.getChildren().add(menuItem);
    menuItem = new MenuItem();
    menuItem.setValue("Jeunes diplomés");
    menuItem.setUrl("#");
    submenu1.getChildren().add(menuItem);

    submenu.getChildren().add(submenu1);
    menuItem = new MenuItem();
    menuItem.setValue("Clothes");
    menuItem.setUrl("#");
    submenu.getChildren().add(menuItem);

    simpleMenuModel.addSubmenu(submenu);
    menuItem = new MenuItem();
    menuItem.setValue("Clothe");
    menuItem.setUrl("#");
    simpleMenuModel.addMenuItem(menuItem);

}

public MenuModel getSimpleMenuModel() {
    return simpleMenuModel;
}
```

here the xhtml:
`<p:menubar model="#{menuBean.simpleMenuModel}"/>`

now in primefaces 4 the classes/interfaces seems to be changed, and i don't know to do it in this version.
can anyone help please !!!.

Comment: In PrimeFaces 4, the `Submenu` is only an interface, you may want to instantiate e.g. `DefaultSubMenu`. The same goes for `MenuItem`. Also, at the end of model creation, you'll need to call `simpleMenuModel.generateUniqueIds();`.

Comment: hi veronika can provide a small example please??, and think you for responding so soon.

Answer (score 5):

Please, have a look at the page:

[PrimeFaces - New MenuModel](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2594).

Simple example:

```
MenuModel model = new DefaultMenuModel();

DefaultSubMenu subMenu = new DefaultSubMenu("some submenu");
DefaultMenuItem menuItem = new DefaultMenuItem("some item");
subMenu.addElement(menuItem);

model.addElement(subMenu);

model.generateUniqueIds();
```

Method `generateUniqueIds()` will spare you from creating and setting id strings yourself.

Comment: How do you add the model.getElements() to a Menubar Object now?

Answer (score 1):

Personally i create my menu dynamically like this on primeface 4.0 :

Bean:

```
private MenuModel menumodel = new DefaultMenuModel();

//create the first menu item
DefaultMenuItem accueil = new DefaultMenuItem("Accueil");
accueil.setStyleClass("accueil");
accueil.setUrl("/accueil.jsf");
this.menumodel.addElement(accueil);
//Start here i create submenu with personal access for all user
for (Autorisation auto : this.permList) {
    if (auto.getRessource().getSousMenu() != null) {
        if (auto.getRessource().getSousMenu().size() != 0) {
            //Create submenu
            DefaultSubMenu submenu = new DefaultSubMenu();
            submenu.setIcon(null);
            submenu.setLabel(auto.getRessource().getMenu());
            this.menumodel.addElement(submenu);
            for (Ressource r : auto.getRessource().getSousMenu()) {
                //Feed submenu with menu item
                DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem();
                item.setValue(r.getMenu());
                item.setUrl(r.getPath());
                submenu.addElement(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```