# How to create a dynamic p:menuButton inside a jsf dataTable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, facelets

I have a p:menuButton in a p:column in a p:dataTable.

So far everything works fine.

Now I want to make the menuButton dynamic. However c:foreach is evaluated before rendering the table and primefaces doesn't like to use ui:repeat inside the p:menuButton.

How can I create a number of p:menuitem dynamically based on a collection on the row item I am looping over, i.e. what should I do instead of ?:someKindOfLoop in the example below?

```
<p:dataTable value='#{something.collection}' var='item'>
...
    <p:column>
    ...
        <p:menuButton value="Actions">
            <p:menuitem value="View ..."
              ...>
                <f:param name="something" value="#{item.id}"/>
            </p:menuitem>
            <?:someKindOfLoop x="#{item.subCollection}" y="var">
                <p:menuitem value="View sub list "
                  ...>
                    <f:param name="#{var.name}" value="#{var.id}"/>
                </p:menuitem>
            </?:someKindOfLoop>

        </p:menuButton>
    ...
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Googling yields a number of similar cases, however I haven't found one yet that wasn't either about dynamically creating columns (like this: [Why can <c:forEach> or <ui:repeat> not access <p:dataTable var>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021036/why-can-cforeach-or-uirepeat-not-access-pdatatable-var#29031236) ) or that doesn't deal with primefaces.

Comment: Only `<c:forEach` runs early enough to create new control items like `<p:anyControl`. After that, it's not permittet to change the count of control items in a page. It's possible if you use `<c:forEach` with runtime values, but you will get some strange results. Because your data source is a `<p:...` control item, there is no way to build some more. If there is a limit of possibilities, you may build always max. possible items with `<c:forEach varStatus="var"` and insert a `rendered="#{bean.rendertest(var.index)`. Not nice but possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PrimeFaces `p:menuButton`, like many other components, including most menu components, supports the model attribute. This is mentioned on [page 329 in the PF6 documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_0.pdf#329). The 'Dynamic menus` section of this component refers to the 'common' dynamic menus section on [page 323](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_0.pdf#323). There you can read how to do this.

And to prevent this answer to be a 'link only' (to external sites, here is the sort of duplicate of this question: [Primefaces : how to create <p:menubar> dynamically in primefaces 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481970/)

Comment: I guess this is what we looked for. As we are trying to add this to every row in a table I guess we will try something along the lines of <p:menu model="#{menuView.createModel(item)}" />. Will try that now. Thanks a lot!